# Select statements in a Multi-join SOQL query

Tags: soql

```
SELECT accountid, name, account.name, account.edit_date_funded__c, 
                  account.createddate, date_lead__c, ln_score_again__c, 
                  createddate, lead.ln_score__c 
FROM Opportunity
WHERE accountid IN (select id from account) 
        AND accountid IN (select convertedaccountid from lead)
```

I get an error for lead.ln_score__c or when I try to select anything from lead.

"Didn't understand relationship 'lead' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name."

Can someone tell me what I need to fix.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no field called lead on the Opportunity.  You can see all of the available fields in the [Opportunity object documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm.).

There is a field called ConvertedOpportunityId on the [Lead object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm) which will be set if the Lead has been converted to an Opportunity. You can query from the Lead to the Opportunity field through it.  For example:

```
Select Id, ConvertedOpportunity.Name
From Lead
```

If you have a custom Lookup field on the Opportunity for a Lead then you would access it by appending the ‘__r’ as the error states. For example: `lead__r.ln_score__c`.

Salesforce has good explanation of [Relationship Queries in their docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) that might be helpful.

Comment: ConvertedOpportunityId instead of  ConvertedOpportunity.Name.